Javascript html table get clicked cell value and column(th) ID
i am trying to get a clicked Table Cell value and corresponding Column ID (th.id)
i need in the $msg the following.

Clicked Cell Value (easy (e.target.innerHTML)
Get the cellIndex from the cell (td) (easy e.target.cellIndex)
corresponding column (th) ID for the same  e.target.cellIndex
*** when i comment the foreach the code work.
the foreach apparently not working
Please help

    function onTableCellClicked(e){
     //  alert('table cell clicked value ='+e.target.innerHTML);
       if(e.target.innerHTML && window.chrome.webview){
        $ind=e.target.cellIndex
        $Msg=e.target.innerHTML
       var TTH = document.getElementById('NGTable1 th');
       TTH.forEach(function(th) {
         if (th.cellIndex==$ind){$Msg=$Msg+'|'+th.id}
        })
       window.chrome.webview.postMessage($Msg);
     }  
   }


document.getElementById() only returns one element, not a list of elements. There's nothing to loop over. Also, NGTable1 th is not a valid ID, you can't have spaces in IDs. I think you meant document.querySelector().

There's no need to loop over them. You can simply use TTH[$ind]
